# Disable external access to EAC on Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange

I followed the instructions I saw on a dozen pages. Installed [IP Address and Domain Restrictions], edited unspecified clients to Deny, added a single internal IP allow, iisreset. Yet I'm able to reach EAC from outside.

Same instructions on a dozen pages but here is a couple for reference:

- https://blog.expta.com/2018/10/how-to-block-external-access-to.html
- https://www.blackmanticore.com/275fab1aa356742558b9f77f3050554e

Comment: Hi, is there any update? If your problem has been fixed and the below answer is helpful to you, you could mark the best answer; If there is any similar issue after that, you're welcome to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the configuration did you configure for unspecified clients?
[image]

Did you restart IIS before accessing ECP externally?

Comment: As my post states, I have Deny for unspecified and I restarted using iisreset

Comment: What the issue did you encounter? You could see the ECP web page and access it from outside but couldn't sign in your account, right? If so, as **AndyDavid** said in the similar thread "**Block Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 Exchange Admin Center (EAC) website from Internet**" (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/58814/block-microsoft-exchange-server-2016-exchange-admi.html), if we setup IP Address and Domain Restrictions for ecp, users from outside could still see the web page.

Comment: Ivan_Wang, that was it. I wrongly assumed it wasn't blocking because the page was still coming up. I did not test login. Now that I did, I see that it's not allowed. So this whole things was my own mistake/oversight.